# Unmatched column Data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, toad

I have a situation as explained below

select * from version

```
vno     name    sal     deptno      -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1       XXX     1000    10          -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   
2       YYY     1000    10          -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -
```

here i need a simple plsql code which returns unmacthed column_name as well data too.

I need the following output:

```
vno      1      2
name    xxx    yyy
```

here my columns and data both are to be generic.

Comment: The column names are available in the system view USER_TAB_COLS. UNPIVOT or PIVOT is probably useful (I would try UNPIVOT first).

Answer (score 0):

select vno,name from version where column_name != 'your variable';
//hope it works

Comment: Hello, here i don't konw how many columns did my table has. i have 58 tables to be applicable for the same situation

Comment: sorry i have not gone through this sort of problem but cant you do like this:

var tablename="SHOW Full TABLES from db_name]";
select * from version where table != tablename;